# insert data to mysql inwith php

Tags: php

In the below script, I'm trying to submit many from php to mysql in one table,

```
<?php
include "koneksi.php";

$soal[] = $_POST['soal'];

$j1=$_POST['jwb_1'];
$j2=$_POST['jwb_2'];
$j3=$_POST['jwb_3'];
$j4=$_POST['jwb_4'];
$j5=$_POST['jwb_5'];
$kunci=$_POST['kunci'];
$beban=$_POST['beban'];
$id=$_POST['id_soal'];
$course=$_SESSION['course'];
$mgu=$_SESSION['m`enter code here`inggu'];
$jum=$_POST['jum'];

$i=$id;
for ($i=1;$i<=$jum;$i++){
    $sq=mysql_query("insert into
                     t_soal(id_soal, course, soal, jawab_1, 
                     jawab_2, jawab_3, jawab_4, jawab_5, beban, 
                     kunci, minggu)
                     values('$i', '$course', '$soal', '$j1', 
                     '$j2', '$j3', '$j4', '$j5', '$beban', 
                     '$kunci', '$mgu')");
}
```

Comment: What $_SESSION['m`enter code here`inggu']????

Comment: Describe your problem, please.

Comment: hi lucas,sorry this wrong, corect script is $mgu=$_SESSION['minggu'];

Comment: SO WHAT IS THE PROBLEM?????

Comment: i have many text area, the text area  will insert to db, but the data inserted only last data in text area.

Comment: i will give picture but in the coment i cant upload anything

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to never put your data this way. Please, be aware of SQL Injection, XSS attacks... You need to validate your inputs, parameterized and clean it. Then, put it in your mysql using SQL statement.

And try to use a good form for your SQL statement. Like this :

```
INSERT INTO `databaseName`.`tableName` (`id_soal`, `course`) VALUES ($i, $course);
```

Everything should work..(Be sure to connect correctly to your database too!)